# AWS Java SDK SSL Certificates

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a JBoss AS7 connecting to AWS and specifically to S3 over the AWS SDK for Java, I have the access and secret keys, and everything runs fine. I use the S3 for various file sharing.

The JBoss' datasource connects to AWS RDS. I've enabled SSL encryption for the datasource - I have the `rds-ca-2019-root.pem` in my truststore configured in my standalone.xml, and my RDS datasource connects and verifies the SSL with no problem.
However, when I try to connect to S3 over the SDK (when the truststore with the RDS cert is enabled), I get the following exception:

`Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

So, no truststore enabled: I can connect to S3 through SDK just fine. When I enable the truststore with the RDS certificate: my SDK -> S3 connection breaks.

I can't figure out what certificate I need to add to the truststore so that the SDK can work, or do I need to configure the SDK to use TLS somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out what was wrong: not having any sort of custom truststore defined for my jboss meant that the AWS SDK pulled the regular cacerts truststore from `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts`. Defining my own truststore (which lacked all the certificates from the cacerts truststore) - meant that AWS SDK had nowhere to fetch the regular certificates.

So to solve it: I imported my `rds-ca-2019-root.pem` into the above mentioned cacerts file and linked that as my server truststore in my standalone.xml.

Comment: How did you link it? I am going through the same problem

Comment: @GabrielRobaina Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138940/import-pem-into-java-key-store?

Comment: I don't recall from the top of my head as it's been a while now :/

Answer (score 3):

Ognjen's answer helped me to troubleshoot this issue. I had same problem and the issue was due to AWS SDK using custom truststore that I built for RDS connection. I had specified the custom truststore by setting `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` parameter explicitly.

**The solution I applied:**
I used the script in [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect_programmatically.html) documentation to import the `rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem` into the `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts` (You may find this `cacerts` file inside the `jre/lib/security` folder if you have the JDK installed.). Then I removed the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` setting that I had. Then java started using the default `cacerts` file and now all is good.

The default password for java default truststore is `changeit`.

Comment: The default password is `changeit` not `chageit` if anyone is having trouble with that

Answer (score 1):

Ognjen and Asanka propose to use the same truststore for whole application (or application server) that is not suitable in some cases. But AWS Java SDK provides `ApacheHttpClientConfig` via `ClientConfiguration` to affect Apache HTTP client, e.g.:

```
import com.amazonaws.ApacheHttpClientConfig;
import com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import org.apache.http.conn.socket.ConnectionSocketFactory;

SSLContext myContext = ...
HostnameVerifier myVerifier = ...

ConnectionSocketFactory factory = new SdkTLSSocketFactory(myContext, myVerifier);

ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
clientConfiguration.getApacheHttpClientConfig().setSslSocketFactory(factory);

AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
    .withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration)
    .build();
```

Edit: See also [StackOverflow question #47913449](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913449).

Comment: Thx, is this possible in AWS S3 Java SDK 2.x, and code reference please?