# Java Microservice not able to communicate with AWS Athena Client: Handshake_Failure

Tags: java, ssl, java-7, tls1.2, amazon-athena

I had a microservice running fine in production till yesterday (22nd Sept), today it started giving handshake_failure while communicating with the AWS Athena.

I have checked the SSL Certificates and it seems to be fine and valid.

**Environment:** Java 7, Tomcat 7

**Framework:** Spring 3

**dependency:**
aws-java-sdk-athena: 1.11.522

**Stacktrace:**-

````
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:927)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.ccclogic.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    com.ccclogic.security.filters.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    com.ccclogic.common.security.filters.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:90)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    com.ccclogic.core.filter.AcegiAjaxFilter.doFilterInternal(AcegiAjaxFilter.java:51)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    com.ccclogic.core.filter.HttpsCookieFilter.doFilter(HttpsCookieFilter.java:46)
root cause

com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1175)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1121)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512)
    com.amazonaws.services.athena.AmazonAthenaClient.doInvoke(AmazonAthenaClient.java:1369)
    com.amazonaws.services.athena.AmazonAthenaClient.invoke(AmazonAthenaClient.java:1336)
    com.amazonaws.services.athena.AmazonAthenaClient.invoke(AmazonAthenaClient.java:1325)
    com.amazonaws.services.athena.AmazonAthenaClient.executeStartQueryExecution(AmazonAthenaClient.java:1045)
    com.amazonaws.services.athena.AmazonAthenaClient.startQueryExecution(AmazonAthenaClient.java:1017)
    com.ccclogic.awsservices.athena.AthenaClient.submitAthenaQuery(AthenaClient.java:57)
    com.ccclogic.awsservices.athena.AthenaClient.queryForList(AthenaClient.java:126)
    com.ccclogic.dao.impl.aws.IVRAnalyticsDaoImpl.getIVRs(IVRAnalyticsDaoImpl.java:450)
    com.ccclogic.business.impl.IVRAnalyticsServiceImpl.getIVRs(IVRAnalyticsServiceImpl.java:45)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor397.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.getIVRs(Unknown Source)
    com.ccclogic.controller.IVRAnalyticsController.getIVR(IVRAnalyticsController.java:106)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor396.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.invokeNamedMethod(MultiActionController.java:471)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.handleRequestInternal(MultiActionController.java:408)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.ccclogic.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    com.ccclogic.security.filters.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    com.ccclogic.common.security.filters.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:90)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    com.ccclogic.core.filter.AcegiAjaxFilter.doFilterInternal(AcegiAjaxFilter.java:51)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    com.ccclogic.core.filter.HttpsCookieFilter.doFilter(HttpsCookieFilter.java:46)
root cause

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
    org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
    com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:142)
    org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
    org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor203.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)
    com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy68.connect(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1297)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512)
    com.amazonaws.services.athena.AmazonAthenaClient.doInvoke(AmazonAthenaClient.java:1369)
    com.amazonaws.services.athena.AmazonAthenaClient.invoke(AmazonAthenaClient.java:1336)
    com.amazonaws.services.athena.AmazonAthenaClient.invoke(AmazonAthenaClient.java:1325)
    com.amazonaws.services.athena.AmazonAthenaClient.executeStartQueryExecution(AmazonAthenaClient.java:1045)
    com.amazonaws.services.athena.AmazonAthenaClient.startQueryExecution(AmazonAthenaClient.java:1017)
    com.ccclogic.awsservices.athena.AthenaClient.submitAthenaQuery(AthenaClient.java:57)
    com.ccclogic.awsservices.athena.AthenaClient.queryForList(AthenaClient.java:126)
    com.ccclogic.dao.impl.aws.IVRAnalyticsDaoImpl.getIVRs(IVRAnalyticsDaoImpl.java:450)
    com.ccclogic.business.impl.IVRAnalyticsServiceImpl.getIVRs(IVRAnalyticsServiceImpl.java:45)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor397.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.getIVRs(Unknown Source)
    com.ccclogic.controller.IVRAnalyticsController.getIVR(IVRAnalyticsController.java:106)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor396.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.invokeNamedMethod(MultiActionController.java:471)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.handleRequestInternal(MultiActionController.java:408)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.ccclogic.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    com.ccclogic.security.filters.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    com.ccclogic.common.security.filters.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:90)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    com.ccclogic.core.filter.AcegiAjaxFilter.doFilterInternal(AcegiAjaxFilter.java:51)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    com.ccclogic.core.filter.HttpsCookieFilter.doFilter(HttpsCookieFilter.java:46)```

Any help is appreciated
````

Comment: Your application is calling something, and when trying to it gets rejected by that something during the SSL handshake. First identify what that something is (check the stacktraces for classes of your application - i guess com.ccclogic.dao.impl.aws.IVRAnalyticsDaoImpl.getIVRs() is the relevant part -, see which services you call from those classes), then ask them what they changed or what reason they can see for the handshake failure from their side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've encountered this very same problem on 21st Sept 2021 on our legacy pipeline (Java7/JBoss7) using an older version of the AWS SDK (1.11.132)

It looks like there has been a change on the AWS Athena endpoint which is now using a TLS configuration that is not a default option within our versions Java 7. Thankfully other AWS services that we use have not been affected.

We validated this was localised to Java 7 by writing some simple standalone code using the `AthenaClient` and ran it with both Java7/Java8 and with newer versions of the AWS SDK.

We're not in a position to upgrade our pipeline to Java 8 or above, however we've managed a Java 7 workaround which customises the `AthenaClient` to force it to use `TLS1.2`

This was produced with the help of the following pages:

- https://www.baeldung.com/java-7-tls-v12
- [Amazon SDK not using custom default SSL Socket Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913449/amazon-sdk-not-using-custom-default-ssl-socket-factory)

```
import com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.ClientConfigurationFactory;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.athena.AmazonAthena;
import com.amazonaws.services.athena.AmazonAthenaClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.athena.model.ListNamedQueriesRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.athena.model.ListNamedQueriesResult;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(SSLContext.getDefault().getSupportedSSLParameters().getProtocols()));

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sslContext.init(null, null, new SecureRandom());

        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                sslContext,
                new String[]{"TLSv1.2"},
                null,
                SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());

        ClientConfigurationFactory clientConfigurationFactory = new ClientConfigurationFactory();
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = clientConfigurationFactory.getConfig();
        clientConfiguration.getApacheHttpClientConfig().withSslSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory);

        System.out.println("Hello Athena!");
        AmazonAthena athena = AmazonAthenaClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withClientConfiguration(
                        clientConfiguration
                )
                .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)
                .build();


        ListNamedQueriesRequest req = new ListNamedQueriesRequest();
        ListNamedQueriesResult res = athena.listNamedQueries(req);
        System.out.println("Named Query Ids:");
        for (String id : res.getNamedQueryIds()) {
            System.out.println(id);
        }
    }
}
```

With this we've been able to interact with Athena using Java 7 without the recent SSL handshake errors.

Answer (score -1):

You can try first to debug SSL communication with adding `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to the JVM argument.

You will next see the helloClient calls and the given certificates associated from both sides (the client and the remote server).